# Reading selected portion of line and soting it in array

Tags: python

How do I read every line of a string in Python and store seleted line as an element in an array?

I want to read the file line by line and each line is appended to the end of the array. I could not find how to do this anywhere and I couldn't find how to create an array of strings in Python.

For Example:

Line1=

```
 abc def gef
 lmn qrt was
 lmh kjd lxm

 skd fdj djk
 ndz weg tdg
 ndg has dbg

 pef rah vdg
 pas dgh ghr
 bde ghx ore
```

My output should be:

```
 line1[0]= abc def gef
           lmn qrt was
           lmh kjd lxm

 line1[1]= skd fdj djk
           ndz weg tdg
           ndg has dbg

 line1[2]= pef rah vdg
           pas dgh ghr
           bde ghx ore
```

Comment: Is `line1[0]` (say) a single string containing newlines or a list of strings? What are you "selecting" exactly? What is your input file?

Comment: I am storing the things after newline

Comment: That does not answer anything I just asked.

Comment: I mean, I want to store everything after newline in an array, see my input and output. Thanks

Comment: @Coder see my answer, may be that is what you wanted.

Comment: You want to store this in a list, probably. Arrays are not very needed in python. You can strip out the 'spare lines' by replacing '\n\n' with '\n' in the entire file content. However, it's not clear whether you want a nested list (ie. 3 elements which each have 3 subelements) or a flat list (ie. 3 elements which are each a simple 3-line string.). In your terminology this would be a question of whether you want a 1d or 2d array.

Comment: @Coder Please don't post questions like this where people have to **guess** what input you have and **guess** what output you want, make sure you have real code when asking questions here

Comment: @Jamylak: I am sorry for that, but I have given clear example which shows what input I have and what output I am expecting

Comment: @Coder No, you haven't, `>>> line1[2]= pef rah vdg`
           `pas dgh ghr`
           `bde ghx ore`
           
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax` gives me an error, I should be able to copy paste your input and have it work

Comment: But, I have my variable line1, when I print it, it gives me the format which I have shown, line1[2] should be an array which is my expected output.

Comment: 6 hours since this was posted and no one has managed to figure out what it's asking. Flagging to close as NARQ.

Comment: @Coder I would recommend reading [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and revising your question.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> line1 = """abc def gef
... lmn qrt was
... lmh kjd lxm
...
... skd fdj djk
... ndz weg tdg
... ndg has dbg
...
... pef rah vdg
... pas dgh ghr
... bde ghx ore"""
>>> line1.split("\n\n")
['abc def gef\nlmn qrt was\nlmh kjd lxm', 
 'skd fdj djk\nndz weg tdg\nndg has dbg', 
 'pef rah vdg\npas dgh ghr\nbde ghx ore']
>>> for number, item in enumerate(line1.split("\n\n")):
...     print("Line number {0}".format(number))
...     print(item)
...
Line number 0
abc def gef
lmn qrt was
lmh kjd lxm
Line number 1
skd fdj djk
ndz weg tdg
ndg has dbg
Line number 2
pef rah vdg
pas dgh ghr
bde ghx ore
>>>
```

Comment: I think you understood my question wrong, I want to make an array after every newline

Comment: @Coder: Your question *is* incomprehensible, it seems, to everyone here. Please provide the requested information.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
line1="""abc def gef
lmn qrt was
lmh kjd lxm

skd fdj djk
ndz weg tdg
ndg has dbg

pef rah vdg
pas dgh ghr
bde ghx ore"""


lis = [""]
for line in line1.splitlines():
    if line.strip():
        lis[-1] += "\n"+ line
    else:
        if lis[-1] != "":
            lis.append("")


print lis[0]
print lis[1]
print lis[2]
```

**output:**

```
abc def gef
lmn qrt was
lmh kjd lxm

skd fdj djk
ndz weg tdg
ndg has dbg

pef rah vdg
pas dgh ghr
bde ghx ore
```

Comment: See my input and output, that is what I exactly want

Comment: @Coder I've stored those lines in list only.

Comment: I don't understand your with open function, as I have everthing already stored in line1

Comment: @Coder I've changed that, now I am using a string.

Comment: @Coder: The fact is that "what you exactly want" is ambiguous, given what you've written. Do you want a list 3 items long, with each item being a 3-line string?
Or do you want a list 3 items long, with each item being a list of 3 strings (one per line)?  If you cannot answer this question, you may not understand your own problem well enough to get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: That doesn't matter in each case as whenever there is a two new line, which is blank as I have shown, I want to split that part in array as shown in output.

Comment: @Coder have you tried `line1.split("\n\n")`?

Comment: Yes, I tried your code ashwini but lis[0] gives me all the things and when I print lis[1] it gives list index out of range

Comment: @Coder Either your input data is in some other format or you're trying something wrong, because both my code and `line1.split("\n\n")` return a list with 3 items.

Answer (score 0):

This opens a file and reads all the lines into the variable called `lines`. It also removes the trailing new lines for you.

```
with open('<<FILENAME>>', 'r') as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file.readlines()]
```

Dissected:

`with open...`

Indicates that you're opening a FILENAME for `'r'` reading, and naming the resultant file object `file`.  It will be destroyed for you after the block below it is finished.

`lines =`

Assigns the expression on right hand side to `lines`

`[line.rstrip() for line in file.readlines()]`

Creates the list out of the files contents:

1. `line.rstrip()` happens to each line in the result of `file.readlines()` it removes the trailing new line.
2. `for line in` is the way to enumerate the results of something in place (see [Python List Comprehensions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)).
3. `file.readlines()` returns a list of all the lines (with their line endings) split by new line.